# How to setup login with Ruby API in Android application?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I’m trying to make an android app with an api made in Ruby on rails application.
I’m wondering how to keep user login information in the android application. And also once the user is logged in, then the device(mobile) can access to a database with Ruby application.

In the Ruby app, the user account method is implemented with a Devise gem.

When I request the post with email and password, the output is gathered at “buffer”.  This buffer has data ( when the user puts the correct information – password and email address, the output is a token or “ok” like string. ) But I don't know which type of information I have to keep for this situation.

After this I am a bit lost what to do for the next step. In the Rails app, “current_user” is stored in the session and whenever user navigate the website, this current_user exists unless logged out.

But I’m here using API and I don’t know how Android App retain the user info here.

The user model in Rails has attributes: email, first_name, last_name, etc.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.sitename.com/api/v1/sessions");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

String urlParameters = "email=emailaddress@gmail.com&password=123123123";
DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
dStream.flush();
dStream.close();

InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line).append("\n");
}

reader.close();
return buffer.toString();
//I fill something needs to be done here.
```

And after that, how can we tell to the Ruby Application that the user is logged in? Which type of API I have to make in this situation?

The below is the ruby method for the API ( sessions ). 
The access address is "/api/v1/sessions".

```
module Beta
    class Currency < Grape::API
        version 'v1', using: :path
        format :json #if we put like this, this page would have a json formatted output.

        rescue_from :all

        #http://localhost:3000/api/v1/beta/exchange?amount=4.5#
        #api/v1/+resource name/+method_name

        error_formatter :json, lambda { |message, backtrace, options, env|
            {
                status: 'failed',
                message: message,
                error_code: 123
            }
        }

       resource :sessions do
       desc "Authenticate user and return user object / access token"

       params do
         requires :email, type: String, desc: "User email"
         requires :password, type: String, desc: "User Password"
       end

       post do
         email = params[:email]
         password = params[:password]

         if email.nil? or password.nil?
           error!({error_code: 404, error_message: "Invalid Email or Password.type0"},401)
           return
         end

         user = User.where(email: email.downcase).first
         puts "되고 있나?"

         if user.nil?
           error!({error_code: 404, error_message: "Invalid Email or Password.type1"},401)
           return
         end

         if !user.valid_password?(password)
           error!({error_code: 404, error_message: "Invalid Email or Password.type2"},401)
           return
         else
           #user.ensure_authentication_token
           #user.save
           #{status: 'ok', token: user.authentication_token}.to_json
          {status: 'ok', token: "logged_in#{user.id}#{user.email}"}.to_json
         end
       end


    #curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"ddd@gmail.com,"password":"123123123"}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions

       desc "Destroy the access token"
       params do
         requires :access_token, type: String, desc: "User Access Token"
       end
       delete ':access_token' do
         access_token = params[:access_token]
         user = User.where(authentication_token: access_token).first
         if user.nil?
           error!({error_code: 404, error_message: "Invalid access token."},401)
           return
         else
           user.reset_authentication_token
           #{status: 'ok'}
         end
       end
     end
```

..

Please give me any hunch! I'm so looking forward to hearing any comments from the experts like you! (:

Answer (score 1):

Well all sessions does is access a cookie on your browser and stores up to 4kb of data. It looks like your API method is working in the same way as rails normally does. You should check the rails guides on how sessions actually work http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark

Check the section about session storage. Then I would find out if your android application is able to persist data with cookies, if so you should hypothetically be able to access it through a session.

Comment: Thank you so much! (: So what I decided to do was to get "token" and user would be identified with that token that would be stored in the Android app. If this not null, then user would be able to use this token to navigate the API without being asked more. But if this token is expired it's going to redirect the user to login again and have to get new token. Thank you so much!